# Why is the Compile menu option is grayed out in my Visual Studio C++ makefile project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile

So recently I was poking around C++ makefile projects using "Visual Studio 2012".
I grasped the concept of creating a proper makefile (file) and integrating it in the Visual Studio IDE in order to Build/Clean my project using just the GUI menu options, without the Command Line.

The only problem I have now is to compile a single file through the menu option:
Build->Compile (or the keys combination Ctrl+F7 in my case) which is disabled (grayed out) for some reason.

So first off I would like to know if that behavior is standard for C++ Makefile projects using Visual Studio or I might be missing something out.
In case the Compile menu option should be enabled, I would like to know how to setup my makefile project correspondingly.